# Importing a new library - attributes

Tags: android, import

I want to use this library [LIB](https://github.com/rey5137/material)
I have done steps "Getting Started". Imported AAR file, added maven repo and dependencies. I copied files from zip to the folder that was created while AAR importing. When I want to use custom textview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.rey.material.widget.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    style="@styles/Material.Widget.TabPageIndicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

I get error:

> Error:(9, 16) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@styles/Material.Widget.TabPageIndicator').

What could I do?

Comment: Why are you not using Gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using android studio - which I hope you do, you can easily add this library using Gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
}
```

But do not forget to include these required libraries as per the README text of the same library:

In general, have your `build.gradle` file looking like this under dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

  ...
  compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
}
```

Next, sync your project files and you should be set!

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Please tell me if the whole zip (.idea, app, gradle, src, material, src ect.) should be placed in root/material-1.2.4 ?

Comment: Don't use the zip file; just add the lines above and if you have already added some files from the library using other means, remove them.

Comment: Thanks, it's embarassing, but I didn't know that gradle can autodownload libs :D